# Load Image in RecycleView with Picasso

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, imageview, picasso

Hi guys i have an problem,
I have a list and I have to view it in a list using the reycleview but when I go to the image via cericare phat and to do this use picasso

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    this.viewHolder=viewHolder;
    if(scheduler.size()>=1){
        viewHolder.time.setText(scheduler.get(i).getTime());
        viewHolder.data.setText(scheduler.get(i).getData());
        viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeItem(i);
            }
        });


        String phat=scheduler.get(i).getImageString();
        //result paht:  content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A445
        Picasso.with(c).load(phat).into(viewHolder.img);//does not display the image




        viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new MyClikListener(i));
        viewHolder.time.setOnClickListener(new MyClikListener(i));
        viewHolder.data.setOnClickListener(new MyClikListener(i));
        viewHolder.card_view_reminder.setOnClickListener(new MyClikListener(i));
    }

}
```

I also tried converting the pat in a URI but nothing.
Making debugging tells me onBitmapFailed

Comment: What's the problem, does the app crash? or the image simply doesn't load?

Comment: Do you get any error? To log error messages create a Picasso instance with builder. 
`Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(c).listener(...).build()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
  new DownloadImage(yourImageView).execute(URL);
```

create AsyncTask for download image from background process

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    CircleImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = (CircleImageView) bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

It will work for all..

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
Picasso.with(c).load(new File(phat)).into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

Hope this helps.